# Storing the results from run query into a table in dbt

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, dbt

I am calling this store procedure in dbt. How do I store the results using a select statement into a temp table?

```
{% set results= run_query('call mystoredproc()') %}
 {% do log("Printing table" , info=True) %}
 {% do results.print_table() %}
 {% set sql %}
 select * from results <<--- how to store the result into  a temp table
{% end set %}  

 {% do run_query(create_table_as(True, tmp_relation, sql)) %}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use the materialization which is a strategy for persisting the dbt models in a warehouse. You can configure the materialization in the project.yml file or configure it directly inside the sql files as:

```
{{ config(materialized='table | view |', sort='timestamp', dist='user_id') }}

select *
from ...
```

For more info check the [Materialization docs](https://docs.getdbt.com/docs/building-a-dbt-project/building-models/materializations).

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem when trying to create a table that I could join later on in the same model. Turned out all I needed to do was:

```
with (call mystoredproc())
as temp_table select ...
```